# Jquery Easy UI: Insert textbox in datagrid view

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-easyui

I am using jquery easy ui plugin.I want to insert text box in a datagrid view. [Want to insert text box.](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=)

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe not the best way, but you can change Dom with some jQuery  like :

```
$('td[field="columnname"').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).find('div').text()+'"');
});
```

I haven't test it ;)

Comment: And what about the "Row Editing DataGrid" option? In the left menu of your link, you'll find it. http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Comment: @JoDevI have to insert text box in a datagrid,I don't have to use inline editing for datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatter for that column,

```
<th field="textcolumnid" width="80" formatter="gettextbox" >

function gettextbox(value,row,index)
{
  return "<input type='text'  value='"+value+"' onChange=textboxChecked("+index+",this);>";
}
```